# golang how can these two functions be combined?

Tags: go

I want to learn to write clean code in golang, my problem is: I have two function and I need to combined to become only one, this is my actual code:

```
func db_execute(sql_cmd string) bool {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysql_login)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql_cmd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }
    _, err = stmt.Exec()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func db_tabela_select(cod_cliente string) (id string, cod1 string, cod2 string, cod3 string) {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysql_login)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = db.QueryRow("select id, cod1, cod2, cod3 from db_tabela WHERE `cliente`=? LIMIT 1;", cod_cliente).Scan(
                        &id, &cod1, &cod2, &cod3)

    switch {
        case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
                log.Printf("No codice cliente with that ID.")
        case err != nil:
                log.Printf("database select problems")
        default:
                fmt.Printf("Client code is %s %s %s\n", cod1, cod2, cod3)
    }

    return id, cod1, cod2, cod3
}
```

How can I combine these 2 function in one? These functions have different input and different output.

Comment: Why do you need/want to combine these functions? What is the actual goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't "combine" those functions. What's common in them, move them "out", e.g. to a 3rd function which can be called by these 2.

Also, connecting to a DB should not be a "local" operation, it should only be done once, e.g. in a package `init()` function.

Moreover, functions that may fail (db operations are typical examples of these) should return an error, so it can be inspected and dealt with at the caller.

This is a simpler, more robust and more idiomatic solution to your example:

```
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "db_url_string")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func dbExecute(sql_cmd string) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql_cmd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = stmt.Exec()
    return err
}

func dbTabelaSelect(cod_cliente string) (id, cod1, cod2, cod3 string, err error) {
    query := "select id, cod1, cod2, cod3 from db_tabela WHERE 'cliente'=? LIMIT 1"
    err = db.QueryRow(query, cod_cliente).Scan(&id, &cod1, &cod2, &cod3)
    return
}
```

Example using these functions:

```
func main() {
    defer db.Close() // Graceful shutdown

    if err := dbExecute("some_SQL"); err != nil {
        fmt.Print("SQL execution failed: %v", err)
    }

    id, cod1, cod2, cod3, err := dbTabelaSelect("someID")
    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        log.Printf("No codice cliente with that ID.")
    case err != nil:
        log.Printf("database select problems")
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Client code is %s %s %s %s\n", id, cod1, cod2, cod3)
    }
}
```